# cookie not in request with ios12 device

Tags: asp.net, .net, facebook, asp.net-core, ios12

so since I upgraded my phone to ios12, I'm unable to login to a site i'm developing (.net core 2); I login via facebook, and when facebook redirects to my endpoint, the cookies are not in the request, so when this line runs:

```
ExternalLoginInfo info = await _signInManager.GetExternalLoginInfoAsync();
```

its always null, I checked the request and there is no cookies, while on other devices/pc the login works perfectly, its only ios12 thats giving me this problem atm

I saw another post that said to set cookies to SameSite = None

```
services.ConfigureApplicationCookie(options =>
        {
            options.Cookie.Path = "/";
            options.Cookie.SameSite = SameSiteMode.None;
            options.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30);
            options.SlidingExpiration = true;
            options.AccessDeniedPath = "/Welcome";
        });
```

but this did not work, anything else I could try?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

so I fix it, it's a similar solution but if you use external login, you have to configure the external cookie to be SameSite = SameSiteMode.None

```
services.ConfigureExternalCookie(options =>
        {
            options.Cookie.SameSite = SameSiteMode.None;
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Expanding on Rob's answer...

Adding the following to my OpenIdConnect authentication block resolved the issue:

```
.Services.ConfigureExternalCookie(options => {
    options.Cookie = new Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.CookieBuilder
    {
        SameSite = Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.SameSiteMode.None
    };
});
```

It looks like the fix will be added to 2.3 - [External authentication failing on iOS 12 #2595](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4/issues/2595)